# Hyperledger fabric error in chaincode update

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm following a tutorial with commercial paper in Hyperledger Fabric docs, and I'm trying to update my chaincode, but I get this error:

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not
> successful, error code 500, msg Channel 'mychannel' has been migrated
> to the new lifecycle, LSCC is now read-only

Firstly, I installed a new chaincode, approved it from both organizations, and committed it. After this, I'm calling the upgrade method like this:

```
peer chaincode upgrade -o localhost:7050 -C mychannel --name papercontract --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -v 0.4 -c '{"Args":[]}'
```

Why am I getting an error?

Comment: It look like upgrade method is redundant. I have upgraded chaincode without it

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because you have applied the new chaincode lifecycle [`peer lifecycle chaincode`](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerlifecycle.html#peer-lifecycle-chaincode) to your chaincode, but now you are trying to update it with the old chaincode lifecycle [`peer chaincode`](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode).

When you already have a channel where there are chaincodes installed with the new lifecycle, [you can't install chaincodes with the old lifecycle on that channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/chaincode_lifecycle.html#deploying-a-chaincode).

You will get the same error you mentioned if you try.